# Achieve Matlab's `num2str` behaviour in Octave

Tags: string, matlab, printf, octave

The following code

```
x = [1.1, 2.22, -3.3; 4.44, 5.55, 6.6];
fmt = '%.16g ';
y = num2str(x, fmt)
```

produces different results in Matlab (R20105b)

```
y =
 1.1 2.22 -3.3
4.44 5.55  6.6
```

and in Octave (4.0.0)

```
y =
1.1 2.22 -3.3
4.44 5.55 6.6
```

The difference is the **alignment**: in Matlab the columns are right-aligned, whereas in Octave they are not aligned.

I'd like to achieve exactly Matlab's behaviour in Octave. Do you know any solution for this? Of course I could write my own function, but maybe there already exists a solution.

*EDIT*

Another difference is how **multidimensional arrays** are treated. For example,

```
x = cat(3, magic(3), -magic(3));
fmt = '%.16g ';
y = num2str(x, fmt)
```

produces in Matlab

```
y =
8  1  6 -8 -1 -6
3  5  7 -3 -5 -7
4  9  2 -4 -9 -2
```

and in Octave

```
y =

8 1 6
3 5 7
4 9 2
-8 -1 -6
-3 -5 -7
-4 -9 -2
```

That is, Matlab attaches the 3D slices along the second dimension, and Octave along the first.

Comment: Exactly! :-) Trying to port to Octave. But `num2str` behaves differently! :-(

Comment: I guess you don't want to estimate field sizes...For fixed-width fields the output is indeed right-justified, if the field is large enough to accommodate the whole column. But then of course the following columns can be unnecessarily far to the right.

Comment: Also, from [the sourceforge docs](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/num2str.html): "`The num2str function is not very flexible. For better control over the results, use sprintf (see ‘Formatted Output’).`"...

Comment: @AndrasDeak The problem is, I'm using `num2str` in MATL and I'd like the behaviour to be consistent when working on Matlab and on Octave

Comment: If my suspicion is correct that the multi-dimensional behaviour of num2str is undocumented, then you might have to implement your own version for both platforms anyway in order to ensure consistence in the future.

Comment: Can you please add a Matlab compatibility bug report on the bug tracker together with some examples from Matlab and Octave which could help developers to adapt the behaviour? And a link to this posting... Thank you

Comment: @Andy Good idea! I suspected there would be something like that (I started using Octave only two days ago). I'll do it, thanks!

Comment: @Andy The message gets cut. I don't know why. I ended up just posting a link to this page in a comment. Here is my attempted bug report: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46770

Comment: the savannah markup syntax can be very frustrating. It's also over sensitive and it will simply drop the rest of the message once it finds something it doesn't like. You need to use [`+verbatim+` blocks](https://savannah.gnu.org/cookbook/?func=detailitem&item_id=125).

Comment: @carandraug Oh, I see the problem now. I used `+verbatim+` to begin _and also to  end_. I didn't notice ending uses `-`. Silly me. Anyway. a preview function would be great. BTW, I just noticed that `im2col(1:8, [2 1])` gives an error in Octave, whereas it gives `[]` in Matlab. Is that intended?

Comment: @carandraug Also, `im2col(cat(3, magic(3), -magic(3)), [1 2])` gives different results. This is probably not important, as `im2col` is not meant to work for 3D arrays

Comment: in Octave, `im2col` is meant to work with any number of dimensions. The result I get makes sense to me. If you get a different result can you please report it? On the case of `im2col(1:8, [2 1])` it's a very corner case. I'd arguee that it's equivalent to `reshape` with incorrect dimensions. Throwing an error makes sense to me. But can you report a separate bug for it as well?

Comment: @carandraug Sure, I'll do that tomorrow

Comment: @carandraug For `x = cat(3, magic(3), -magic(3))`, the result I get in Matlab for `im2col(x, [1 2])` is the same as running `im2col(reshape(x, size(x,1), []), [1 2])` (both in Octave and in Matlab). It seems like Matlab collapses all dimensions beyond the first and then proceeds

Comment: @carandraug [Done](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?46774)

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround than a solution; and I'm not totally satisfied with it. But here it goes. If anyone has a better or more general solution please tell.

The following only works for a *single formatting operator*, as in the example (it doesn't work for something like `fmt = '%.2f %.1f'`), and only for *real (not complex) numbers*. It works for arrays with more than `2` dimensions, mimicking Matlab's behaviour: it collapses all dimensions beyond the first into a single (second) dimension.

```
if ischar(x)
    y = x;
else
    y = sprintf([fmt '\n'], reshape(x,size(x,1),[]).'); %'// each row of y is a string.
                                                        % // '\n' is used as separator
    y = regexp(y, '\n', 'split'); %// separate
    y = y(1:end-1).'; %'// remove last '\n'
    y = cellfun(@fliplr, y, 'uniformoutput', false); %// invert each string
    y = char(y); %// concatenate the strings vertically. This aligns to the left
    y = fliplr(y); %// invert back to get right alignment
    y = reshape(y.',[],size(x,1)).'; %// reshape into the shape of x
    y = strtrim(y); %// remove leading and trailing space, like num2str does
end
```

This produces, both in Matlab in Octave, the same result as produced by `y = num2str(x, fmt)` in Matlab.

It should be noted that when the first input is a char array `num2str` ignores the second input (format specifier) and produces as output the same char array, both in Matlab and in Octave. Thus `num2str('abc', '%f ')` produces `'abc'`. However, `sprintf` works differently: it forces the use of the format specifier, interpreting the chars of the input as ASCII codes if needed. That's why the `if` branch is needed in the above code.